# Why a query on VIEW is executing faster than a query on MATERIALIZED VIEW

Tags: sql, view, query-optimization, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have created two views of a table in snowflake database with same select statement, one is a normal view and the other is a materialized view as below,

```
create view view1
as ( select *
     from customer
     where name ilike 'a%')
```

```
create materialized view view2
as ( select *
     from customer
     where name ilike 'a%')
```

Then queried the views as below,

```
Select *
from view1   ----normal view
```

```
Select *
from view2   -----materialized view
```

(suspended warehouse and resumed to remove any cache before executing above queries individually. I have repeated execution many times in same manner.)

But against expectation, Materialized view is always taking longer than normal view.

Why is this?

Comment: What does the EXPLAIN for each query show?

Comment: what order of magnitude are we talking 10ms vs 11ms or 100ms vs 110ms or 10minutes vs 11minutes?

Comment: The difference is in milliseconds, more like 33ms vs 36ms. But I am expecting query on materialized view to be faster, whatever the magnitude.

Answer (score 1):

It could be a number of things. What I would suggest is here:

1. Ensure that the result cache is turned off

```
ALTER SESSION SET USE_CACHED_RESULT = FALSE
```

2. Run them in a warehouse that's been turned off for hours - In my experience, restarting the virtual warehouse does not completely delete cached data. Do not run the query while the VW is off, manually turn them on first before running the query to avoid query delays to provision the warehouse.
3. Run them and check the ff. in QUERY_HISTORY View to get a better idea of what have happened

- PERCENTAGE_SCANNED_FROM_CACHE
- COMPILATION_TIME
- QUEUED_REPAIR_TIME
- TRANSACTION_BLOCKED_TIME
- EXECUTION_TIME - I believe this holds the actual execution time which excludes the time spent in compilation as opposed to TOTAL_ELAPSED_TIME
- QUEUED_OVERLOAD_TIME

Here the [QUERY_HISTORY](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/account-usage/query_history.html) documentation to get more details

You might also want to check the Query Profile, though I think the query using an MV would show a straightforward single step retrieve but would still be worth checking to compare and understand both queries.

Comment: Thank you for your insights. Actually I was suspending VW and almost immediately resuming it. I didn't think it would make a difference if I waited some time before turning them on again before executing queries. I will try as per your suggestion.

Comment: Sure. You can always look at the PERCENTAGE_SCANNED_FROM_CACHE in QUERY_HISTORY to verify if your query did or did not use the warehouse cache.

Comment: Also, bear in mind that the Query Optimiser can choose to bypass the MV and query the underlying table/view directly - if it thinks that would be quicker

Comment: Keep in mind Result Cache is first level cache and lives in Snowflake's metadata layer; it is different to Virtual Warehouse Cache.
Secondly, Snowflake must keep your MV up to date, so if you have a high-churn table underneath the MV then Snowflake is constantly trying to keep the MV up to date.
Last thing to consider, MV's can be clustered differently to a table so it depends on the query what gets effectively pruned to produce your result.

Comment: Re "optimiser bypassing the MV". Not if you query the MV directly. But this made me realize that in the first query against view1, it is possible for the optimiser to rewrite the query and use the MV (view2) instead. Which is why it's important to check the Query Profile to see what really happened. You can drop or suspend the MV if you don't want it to be used